# Windows IP route metric 0

Tags: windows-10, networking, routing

Have internet connection via ethernet cable. When connect USB wifi adapter to wireless router, system have two default gateway (as expected). When later disconnecting USB adapter from wifi router, two default routes remain in system. According to `netsh in ip sh ro`, default route got by wifi DHCP have metric 0 (`netstat -rn` interestingly show ONLY default route with non-zero metric). According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008 route metric number valid interval is 1-9999. What does mean route metric 0, some specific kind of route or specific route status (inactive?) ??

When remove USB wifi adapter from device, route with metric 0 disappear from system, but performing `netsh interface ip delete destinationcache` change notning.

Anyone know what zero metric mean?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with both USB Internet (HUAWEI) and a regular Ethernet connection for completeness.

In the `netsh in ip sh ro`  output, metric 0 is always just the gateway address.

HUAWEI:   192.168.8.1   Ethernet:  192.168.nnn.1

[image: USB Internet Gateway]

So what you see is normal.

Comment: So if you are connected to internet by both ethernet AND wifi adapters, dont you see two default routes in routing table?

Comment: I only use one connection at one time and see one gateway address metric 0.  If you try two connections you may see two gateways.

Comment: dont know if it play a role, but my ethernet connection utilize static IP settings, "automatic" is checked on "Advanced TCP/IP Settings" tab. But this is intarface metric, rather than route metric.

Comment: As I showed in the screenshot it is always the gateway address event though the column title says Interface.   Still normal.

Comment: https://www.imgpaste.net/image/Ku26oY

Comment: Where you show Metric 0 is a gateway address as I said

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140898/discussion-between-john-and-user2956477).